# ByteArrayBody not always accepted by server

Tags: java, php, apache, post

I wrote a Java application using the Apache HTTP libs that sends a HTTP POST request to a webserver and prints the response. A MultipartEntity with some StringBodies and a ByteArrayBody gets attached to the POST, and then it gets sent.
On the webserver a PHP script dumps all the variables included in the request ($_POST and $_FILES)

Now here's the weird part: While testing on a local testing xampp server, it all works perfectly. The strings are in $_POST and the bytes are in $_FILES. But when I test on a remote server, I only receive the strings and the bytes are gone.

Why is this and can I fix this? Is this due to a security setting on the server?

Java client code:

```
public HttpResponse send(URL url) throws IOException{
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toString());

    MultipartEntity ent = new MultipartEntity();
    ent.addPart("testString1", new StringBody("testValue1"));
    ent.addPart("testString2", new StringBody("testValue2"));
    ent.addPart("testString3", new StringBody("testValue3"));
    ent.addPart("testString4", new StringBody("testValue4"));
    ent.addPart("data", new ByteArrayBody(new byte[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}, "data"));

    httpPost.setEntity(ent);
    return client.execute(httpPost);
}
```

Remote PHP code:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);
    $contents = "Data:\n";
    $contents .= print_r($_POST, true) . "\n";
    $contents .= print_r($_FILES, true) . "\n";
    file_put_contents ( "inputDump.txt" , $contents);
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any logfiles entries on the server?